# JavaScript regular expression for business name with some validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need JavaScript regular expression for business name with following conditions:

1. Numbers, spaces and the following characters are allowed:

   ```
   ~ ` ? ! ^ * ¨ ; @ = $ % { } [ ] |  /. < > # “ - ‘
   ```
2. Should be at least 2 characters one of which must be alpha or numeric character
3. No preceding or trailing spaces

examples:  `Test1`, `Ta`, `A1`, `M's`, `1's`, `s!`, `1!`

I tried following (for time being I used only 3 special characters for testing purpose):

```
^(?=(?:[^\A-Za-z0-9]*[\A-Za-z0-9]){2})[~,?,!]*\S+(?: \S+){0,}$
```

But it doesn't validate `s!` or `1!`.

Comment: Allowed characters:
(~), (`), (?), (!), (^), (*), (¨), (;), (@), (=),($), (%), ({), (}), ([), (]), (|), (\), (/). (<), (>), (#), (“), (.), (,). (-). (‘)

Comment: Did you try anything? Please share your attempts.

Comment: I tried following (for time being I used only 3 special characters for testing purpose) : 
^(?=(?:[^\A-Za-z0-9]*[\A-Za-z0-9]){2})[~,?,!]*\S+(?: \S+){0,}$           
but it doesn't validate s! or 1!

Comment: Condition is that one character has to be alphanumeric or the first character has to be alphanumeric? for example, would "!s" be a valid name?

Comment: !s it's valid. because condition is at least 2 characters one of which must be alpha  OR  numeric character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following to validate:

```
^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9 '~?!]{2,}$
```

And add all the characters tht you want to allow in `[a-zA-Z0-9 '~?!]`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL4tD3/5)

Explanation:

- `^` start of the string
- `(?!\s)` lookahead assertion for `don't start with space`
- `(?!.*\s$)` lookahead assertion for `don't end with space`
- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])` lookahead assertion for `atleast one alpha or numeric character`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 '~?!]` characters we want to match (customize as required)
- `{2,}` match minimum 2 and maximum any number of characters from the previously defined class
- `$` end of the string

Answer (score 0):

/^(?=(?:[^\A-Za-z0-9]*[\A-Za-z0-9]){2})[~,?,!]*\S+(?: \S+){0,}$/;

matches strings that begin with a special character, followed by a word that contains at least two non-alphanumeric characters, followed by an optional space and another word.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).